# How can I embed VLC into my C# Project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, vlc, libvlc

I have been trying to do this for a couple days and I'm getting nowhere. I have used/downloaded the Vlc.DotNet.Core/Interops/Forms built them, and imported the DLLs and my issue is when I try to reference the AXVLC.DLL and try to use the COM plugin in my form.

I get two errors

1. VLC ActiveX Plugin and IE Web Plugin v1 - Failed to import the ActiveX control. Please ensure it is properly registered.
2. VLC ActiveX Plugin and IE Web Plugin v2 - Completely crashes Visual Studio 2015.

I have installed 6+ different nightly releases of VLC player and tried each AXVLC.DLL but they all do the same thing. VLC 3.0.x and VLC 2.2.x

I have also tried it in Visual Studio 2012 with the same results.

Comment: Have you looked at https://libvlcnet.codeplex.com

Comment: Seems to be old and for a version of VLC that's no longer available

Comment: Did you try it? Bindings on native libraries like this are typically late bound, so it may work on a newer version, or work with some minor modification to the source. Binding resolves around a corresponding method in the native lib. Unless those have changed dramatically.

Comment: "LibVLC.NET provides .NET bindings to the LibVLC core library (libVLC) of the VLC media player." Any idea how to download the libVLC? the link sends you to http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc.html but I don't see anywhere to download it

Comment: Are you familiar with NuGet? I just looked on NuGet, and a search on libvlc comes up with a couple of different bindings for libVLC.  Nuget should also take care of the native dependencies for you. https://www.nuget.org/packages/com.ptrampert.LibVLCBind/2.0.2

Comment: I did go through NuGet and LibVLCBind seems to be the same as the Vlc.DotNet.Core/Interops/Forms as it is also a wrapper. My real issue is inserting a component to my form. Say I do use LibVLCBind, doesn't that just help you control the VLC ActiveX Plugin or am I not understanding how this works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96715/discussion-between-blue-eyed-behemoth-and-mutantninjacodemonkey).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use the Vlc.DotNet.Forms from nuget package manager under tools. Usage is quite a bit simpler than ActiveX.

```
FileInfo media = new FileInfo(<fullpath to mediafile>);
VlcControl1.SetMedia(media);
VlcControl1.play();
```

`VlcControl1.Video.Adjustment` (.Enable = true -> under same tree all video settings)
**and**

`VlcControl1.Audio` (all audio settings)

If you have to use ActiveX player I'd go with the WMP (Project -> Add reference -> Windows Media Player (ActiveX). Which basically is few times better and native, if using ActiveX.